# trying to convetr json array to multiple json objects in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, loops

trying to convetr json array to multiple json objects in nodejs looking for help here is my code have tried loops to achieve that but failed just want to send the data as multiple objects not array

```
router.get('/frontpage-mobile', function (req, res, next) {

    qryFilter = { "Product_Group": 'SIMPLE' };

    // if we have a cart, pass it - otherwise, pass an empty object
    var successMsg = req.flash('success')[0];
    var errorMsg = req.flash('error')[0];


    Product.find(qryFilter, function (err, product) {
        // console.log("Product: " + JSON.stringify(product));
        var pro=JSON.stringify(product)
        if (err || product === 'undefined' || product == null) {
            // replace with err handling
            var errorMsg = req.flash('error', 'unable to find product');
            res.send(errorMsg);
        }

        if (!product) {
            req.flash('error', 'Product is not found.');
            res.send('error', 'Product is not found.');
        }
   for(i=0;i<pro.length;i++)
        res.send(pro[i]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// Dummy Mongodb Result Array
        var db_result = [{_id:1,name:"Cake_1"},{_id:2,name:"Cake_2"},{_id:3,name:"Cake_3"}]

```
// define data variable 
var data = { total : 0, dataObj : {} } // default total = 0,  = {}
var dataObj = {}

// convert array to obj
// { key1 : obj1, key2 : obj2, key3 : obj3, ... }
for(var i=0; i < db_result.length;i++){
    let key = "key"+i;
    dataObj[key] = db_result[i];
}

// assign data to variable 
data.total = db_result.length;
data.dataObj = dataObj

// rend back to client
res.send(data);


// Result 
{ 
    "total":3,
    "dataObj":{
        "key0":{"_id":1,"name":"Cake_1"},
        "key1":{"_id":2,"name":"Cake_2"},
        "key2":{"_id":3,"name":"Cake_3"}
    }
}
```